# How to pass C# byte[] to C++ unsigned char * via SWIG?

Tags: c#, c++, char, byte, swig

New to SWIG. I've looked high and low, and can't find a simple example to pass a C# byte[] to C++ unsigned char * via SWIG.

The C++ function looks like:

```
void ClassName::MethodName(const unsigned char *inputData, const int length)
```

The .i file looks like:

```
%module ClassNameSwig
%{
#include "ClassName.h" 
%}
%include "std_string.i" 
%include "arrays_csharp.i"
%include "ClassName.h"
```

The .i compiles. The .cs files compile. Now I need to invoke the method and pass it a byte[] like this:

```
            var inst = new ClassName();
            byte[] byteData = ... ; // (fill with some data)
            inst.MethodName(byteData, byteData.Length);
```

The last line fails to compile: CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char'

Am I missing a typemap? Which one? Cannot find the answer in SWIG C# documentation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How does the C++ function know how long the byte array is? (It matters because we need to make sure the SWIG wrapper complies with that)

Comment: The length of the byte[] has been passed to the C++ code already via another method earlier. Not good design, I know, but not the immediate issue.

Comment: Hi @Flexo, I've modified the signature above to pass the length of the byte[]. Feel free to suggest any changes. I am unable to get the code to even compile. :(